# How can I find my the question I asked?

Tags: support, questions

I asked a question in superuser about 3 hours ago. And then I closed my browser and opened it some time ago. Now I want to see question. I searched and was unable to find it. I don't deleted it. How to find my question ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click your user name at the top to open your profile (do this on the main page, not here on Meta Super User). On the left side, there's the list questions you asked.

[image: Screenshot]

---

Of course, you could also search or browse through your web browsing history to find it among the pages you visited recently.

Comment: Thanks...It helped...